# Date displaying incorrect in Android

Tags: android, date, format

I am developing an application in that when time is 11:26 it is showing 11:07. I used Calendar instance to do.

```
Calendar currentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat ddMMyyyy=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        datenow=ddMMyyyy.format(currentDate.getTime());

        if(currentDate.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==Calendar.PM){
            timenow=currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+":PM";
        }else{
            timenow=currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+":AM";
        }
        new MyToast(this, "Date = "+datenow+" time = "+timenow);
```

The out put is wrong what to do?

Answer (score 0):

you are displaying `month` in place of `minute`. Change your code to my code

```
Calendar currentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat ddMMyyyy=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String datenow = ddMMyyyy.format(currentDate.getTime());

String timenow;
if(currentDate.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==Calendar.PM){
    timenow=currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":PM";
}else{
    timenow=currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":AM";
}
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Date = "+datenow+" time = "+timenow,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

11:07 is displaying because 07 ==> month number in a year. month will be calculated from 0 -> 11

Answer (score 0):

You have mistaken see here `Calendar.HOUR` + `:` + **`Calendar.MONTH`**. It should be as follows,

```
Calendar currentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat ddMMyyyy=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        datenow=ddMMyyyy.format(currentDate.getTime());

        if(currentDate.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==Calendar.PM){
            timenow=currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":PM";
        }else{
            timenow=currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":AM";
        }
        new MyToast(this, "Date = "+datenow+" time = "+timenow);
```

Instead of **MINUTE** you were accessing **MONTH** object of Calendar Class.